# How to search SQL database and display in C# listview

Tags: c#, sql, listview, windowsformshost

I need to filter an SQL database using C# to display it in a windowsFormsHost.

For that, I created a text box in which you input the required string. Using this input, the code uses the text to search through the database and display on clicking a refresh button.

The refresh button works and is done, I just need to create the list with the selected rows according to my filter.

Here is the code, which states that no value is returned:

```
    private string GetPassengerList(string sPasssenger)
    {
    string sPasssengerL = textBoxPassengerName.Text;
        if (sPasssenger.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            string sToTime = dtpToDate.Value.Year.ToString("D4") + @"/" + dtpToDate.Value.Month.ToString("D2") + @"/" + dtpToDate.Value.Day.ToString("D2");
            sToTime += @" " + dtpToTime.Value.Hour.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpToTime.Value.Minute.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpToTime.Value.Second.ToString("D2");
            string sFromTime = dtpFromDate.Value.Year.ToString("D4") + @"/" + dtpFromDate.Value.Month.ToString("D2") + @"/" + dtpFromDate.Value.Day.ToString("D2");
            sFromTime += @" " + dtpFromTime.Value.Hour.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpFromTime.Value.Minute.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpFromTime.Value.Second.ToString("D2");

            string sSqlSelect = @"SELECT Passenger FROM ";
            string sSqlWhere = @" WHERE (Created BETWEEN '" + sFromTime + @"' AND '" + sToTime + @"')";// and (IATA='" + sIata + @"')";
            string sSqlLike = @" LIKE '%" + sPasssengerL + "'%";

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
            try {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sSqlSelect + @"dbo.BagData" + sSqlWhere + sSqlLike, this.dbConnection);
                sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if(!sqlReader.Read()) {
                    sqlReader.Close();
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = sSqlSelect + @"dbo.BagDataHistory" + sSqlWhere + sSqlLike;
                    sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    if(!sqlReader.Read()) {
                        sqlReader.Close();
                        sqlCommand.CommandText = sSqlSelect + @"dbo.BagDataArchive" + sSqlWhere + sSqlLike;
                        sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        if(!sqlReader.Read()) {
                                sqlReader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!sqlReader.IsClosed) {
                    sPasssengerL = this.GetSqlDataString(@"Passenger", sqlReader);
                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(SqlException x) {
                MessageBox.Show(@"GetPassengerName(): SQL Exception: " + x.Message, this.GetHashString("Error"), MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(@"GetPassengerName(): General Exception: " + ex.Message, this.GetHashString("Error"), MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            finally {
                if(sqlReader != null) {
                    if(!sqlReader.IsClosed) {
                        sqlReader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return sPasssengerL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a side not, you should be using Parameters. It's a pretty bad, security wise, to be concatenating strings to form your query. e.g. `select * from @tableName where @Foo = @Bar` then `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "yourTableName");`

Comment: Where is `sSqlWhere` defined?

Comment: @TimothyG. sSqlWhere is defined in my code though i purposely omitted it, my concern is more on sSqlLike

Comment: You should try to include *all* of your code to get the best answers.  You can see already two people posted an answer in reference to this.

Comment: @TimothyG. I did, now, include all of the GetPassengerList function. Noted and will use your advice in future posts, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in the code you posted.

1. Using concatenated strings instead of parameters in your sql query.
2. <s>Re-declaring a variable with the same name as the functions parameter</s>. You are declaring another passenger variable `sPasssengerL` needlessly in the function now.
3. <s>Not returning a string value from the function</s>. Your edited code shows the function returning the seemingly unneeded extra passenger variable `sPasssengerL` now.
4. Your LIKE statement did not include which column it is checking
   against.

I cleaned up the code a little, leaving the `sSqlWhere` in case that was oddly delcared outside your example. This also shows how to add the first column of data to a listview as you've requested.

> **EDIT:** Per your comment on the original question I've updated the code
>   to show your `sSqlWhere` variable.

```
private void GetPassengerList()
{
    string sPassenger = textBoxPassengerName.Text;
    if (sPassenger.Trim().Length > 0)
    {

        string sToTime = dtpToDate.Value.Year.ToString("D4") + @"/" + dtpToDate.Value.Month.ToString("D2") + @"/" + dtpToDate.Value.Day.ToString("D2");
        sToTime += @" " + dtpToTime.Value.Hour.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpToTime.Value.Minute.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpToTime.Value.Second.ToString("D2");
        string sFromTime = dtpFromDate.Value.Year.ToString("D4") + @"/" + dtpFromDate.Value.Month.ToString("D2") + @"/" + dtpFromDate.Value.Day.ToString("D2");
        sFromTime += @" " + dtpFromTime.Value.Hour.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpFromTime.Value.Minute.ToString("D2") + @":" + dtpFromTime.Value.Second.ToString("D2");

        string sSqlSelect = @"SELECT Passenger FROM ";
        string sSqlWhere = @" WHERE (Created BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)";

        // I assume this is looking for passenger. Change appropriately.
        string sSqlLike = @"AND Passenger LIKE @name"; 
        string searchTerm = "%" + sPassenger + "%";

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sSqlSelect + @"dbo.BagData" + sSqlWhere, parentWindow.dbConnection);
            sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (!sqlReader.Read())
            {
                sqlReader.Close();
                sqlCommand.CommandText = sSqlSelect + @"dbo.BagDataHistory" + sSqlWhere + sSqlLike;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", searchTerm));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", sToTime));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", sFromTime));
                sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (!sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    sqlReader.Close();
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = sSqlSelect + @"dbo.BagDataArchive" + sSqlWhere + sSqlLike;
                    sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    // This will loop through your returned data and add
                    // an item to a list view (listView1) for each row.
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();
                        lvItem.SubItems[0].Text = sqlReader[0].ToString();
                        lvItem.SubItems.Add(sqlReader[0].ToString());
                        listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);
                    }
                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
            }
            if (!sqlReader.IsClosed)
            {
                sPassenger = parentWindow.GetSqlDataString(@"Passenger", sqlReader);
                sqlReader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"GetPassengerName(): SQL Exception: " + x.Message, parentWindow.GetHashString("Error"), MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"GetPassengerName(): General Exception: " + ex.Message, parentWindow.GetHashString("Error"), MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlReader != null)
            {
                if (!sqlReader.IsClosed)
                {
                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** There are other places this code can be cleaned up and simplified but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Check your variables, you've declared sSqlSelect and sSqlLike but not sSqlWhere which you are using in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

a) your function will not compile: 
- Missing ";" in several lines, 
- local variable declaration "sPessanger" in line 2 conflicts with parameter name ...

b) you never return a value. At least you need a single "return sPassenger;" somewhere in the code to return the selected value.

c) bad style using sql injection. As already stated in the comments, use parameters in your SQL.

d) as far as i can see, you are selecting only a single value from your resultset, or is the GetSqlDataString function supposed to do the job?